# Android: BottomSheetMenuItem doesn't show icon in Menu

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I am trying to show icons in BottomSheeet but only text shows. I read lot of threads on SO but none of them seem to help or are old.

Seeking help on latest android version. Appreciate any help.

```
List<MenuItem> bottomSheetMenuItems = new ArrayList<>(optionsList.size());
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email, 
getContext().getTheme());
MenuItem bottomSheetMenuItem = new BottomSheetMenuItem(
                getContext(),
                someId,
                "Test",
                drawable);

bottomSheetMenuItem.setChecked(true).setChecked(true);
bottomSheetMenuItems.add(bottomSheetMenuItem);

BottomSheet bottomSheet = new BottomSheet
            .Builder(getContext())
            .setTitle("Test Title")
            .setMenuItems(bottomSheetMenuItems)
            .create();

bottomSheet.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

For icons, you would have to create an xml for bottomsheet.

XML example

```
<LinearLayout app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
android:id="@+id/intervalBottomSheet"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="400dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/ic_remove_red_eye_black_24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="MenuItem" />
```

Java code

```
final BottomSheetDialog mBottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(getActivity());
View sheetView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.bottomsheet_interval, null);
mBottomSheetDialog.setContentView(sheetView);
mBottomSheetDialog.show();
```

If your menu items are dynamic and not constant, you could use a recyclerview in the bottomsheetdialog.

With that in mind, you'll need to do this to load the icons

```
ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image);
```